# Difference in EF4 and EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I just upgrade an application to EF6.

My base object Trip contains Reservations.  My reservation object that I am passing into the AddObject and Add function only have the Trip_Id field set i did not set the Trip navigational property to a Trip object.  That being said,  in EF4 after calling the db.SaveChanges the reservation object DOES have the navigational property "Trip" accessible.  However in EF6 this does not happen.  Any ideas?

EF 6 Code

```
 db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
 db.SaveChanges();
 return RedirectToAction("Details", "Trip", new { id = reservation.Trip.Id });
```

EF4 Code

```
 db.Reservations.AddObject(reservation);
 db.SaveChanges();
 return RedirectToAction("Details", "Trip", new { id = reservation.Trip.Id });
```

It seems that EF6 does not have the AddObject and i need to use the Add function.

Comment: That's probably because lazy loading is for some reason disabled - e.g. your navigation property is not virtual or the class is sealed. Did you use lazy loading in your EF4 app?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just create your `reservation` object, or was it loaded from the database?

If you just created it, you have a reference to the actual object, not the proxy that EF will generate.

In that case, I think this might apply (although right at the end, it says that `DbSet.Add()` should call `DetectChanges()` automatically, and your db.Reservations property is likely a `DbSet` type... Hmmm...).

It is possible you might have turned off change tracking for some reason? This might be done for performance reasons.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

> **Synchronizing the changes between the FKs and Navigation properties**
>
> When you change the relationship of the objects attached to the
>   context by using one of the methods described above, the Entity
>   Framework needs to keep foreign keys, references, and collections in
>   sync. The Entity Framework automatically manages this synchronization
>   (also known as relationship fix-up) for the POCO entities with
>   proxies. For more information, see Working with Proxies.
>
> If you are using POCO entities without proxies, you must make sure
>   that the DetectChanges method is called to synchronize the related
>   objects in the context. Note, that the following APIs automatically
>   trigger a DetectChanges call.
>
> DbSet.Add DbSet.Find DbSet.Remove DbSet.Local DbContext.SaveChanges
>   DbSet.Attach DbContext.GetValidationErrors DbContext.Entry
>   DbChangeTracker.Entries Executing a LINQ query against a DbSet

Comment: the reservation object was created not loaded from the database using `Reservation reservation = new Reservation();`.   Then i do `reservation.trip_id=99`  (where 99 is the ID of the trip object);   This reservation object is then passed into the code i posted in my original question and behaves as i described in EF4 and EF6